# How to monitor search queries on ElasticSearch? I want to know what my users are searching for

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Cloud hosted service for elasticsearch and kibana instance. I have already asked help on https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries article from Elastic Cloud team but it is relevant to on-premise cluster

Comment: Use logstash to listen on es port. Parse the querry and index it in es (you need tomake your own parser for each type/index).

Comment: I was looking for a library that would automatically parse them. I do not want the overhead of writing  a parser and sending my logs to an elasticsearch instance. Thanks anyway!